# NPM error in Django application deployment in Render

Tags: node.js, django, npm, deployment, tailwind-css

I’m trying to deploy a Django application in Render. My operating system is Windows. I use tailwind and when it is executed in the Render virtual machine the command 'python manage.py tailwind build' appears the following error of npm:

```
sh: 1: rimraf: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! theme@3.4.0 build:clean: `rimraf ../static/css/dist`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the theme@3.4.0 build:clean script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have in the requirements.txt nodejs==0.1.1 and npm==0.1.1. And in the settings.py: NPM_BIN_PATH = "/usr/bin/npm". Below I show the build.sh file:

```
set -o errexit

pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py tailwind build

if [[ $CREATE_SUPERUSER ]];
then
  python manage.py createsuperuser --no-input
fi
```